# Using conecpt from another applications UI

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to implement the same feature on my application Whatsapp's Swipe to reply..

Will I face legal issues if I use Whatsapp swipe to reply feature on the application, I working on?

Comment: I don't think your problem can be answered well on StackOverflow. If you have any questions regarding copyrights and other laws I'd recommend asking on [the Law StackExchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @THess Thanks for the help.. I'l post the quesion over there! 

Answer (score 0):

Check https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/89475/who-invented-the-swipe-to-gestures

There it is explained in details. Please use correct forums to ask your question.